# Injecting custom service in extending validator service angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am extending validator service of angular 5 .

I want to inject custom service (storageService) in this validator service class how can I do that.

Here is my validator service class code

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable ,Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { StorageService } from '../../shared/service/storage.service';

 // want to inject StorageService in this class
 declare var moment: any;
export class ValidatorService extends Validators {

 static addressValidator(control:FormControl)
  {
     console.log('want to use service here ')
  }
}
```

Here I want to inject `StorageService` in this class usually we inject in constructor

How can I do that here ?

Comment: you can use `@Inject` and inject into it

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable ,Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { StorageService } from '../../shared/service/storage.service';

 @Injectable()
export class ValidatorService {
  moment: any;
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}


 public addressValidator(control:FormControl)
  {
     console.log('want to use service here ');
     if (conditionNotFullfill) {
       return { address: false; }
     }
     return null;

  }

}
```

Now you need to inject your ValidatorService in component by DI
Hope it will help.

Comment: this is not working I have declare in constructor and already call super()

Comment: why u not extending validator ?

Comment: You don't need of it. When you will use your Validation method in Validation array of form then angular automatically pass formcontrol object as parameter to your method. Just validate the value and return null or an object.

Comment: the problem is there is already many functions in this class (I have not copied there code there and all are static ) is there solution to this ? @Sandip

Comment: U have made this public and use  `@Injectable()`

Comment: I'm using in my application in same way. I put all Validation methods in single service class and inject my service in component.

Answer (score 0):

decorate your custom service with @Injectable decorator to notify angular that this service will inject another service

```
@Injectable
export class ValidatorService extends Validators {

    constructor(private storageService: StorageService){}
}
```

and don't forget to add them in app.module in the providers array